# Chocolate distribution

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

### Description:

One day, Dragonfly receives n chocolates. Having decided to distribute the chocolate among his m friends, he comes up with the following rules:

- first he will rank his friends from 1 to m, based on the intimacy of the friendship
- second, if friend at rank i gets x chocolates (so `F[i]=x`), then friend at `x+1` should get no less than x chocolate and no more than `x+k` chocolate (so `x <= F[i+1] <= x +k`), where `k` is a positive number.
- The friend at position one should not get more than k chocolates (so `F[1] <= k`)
- Some friends may get zero chocolates.
- If possible, Dragonfly should be left with no chocolates. He has a toothache and should not be eating candy.

Although not well versed in mathematics,  Dragonfly is eager to know the number of ways that all chocolates could be distributed. So he is asking for your help

### Input:

Input file consists of a series of input lines each defining one case. Input for each case is a single line of three positive integers:

```
N (1 <= n <= 500), m (1 <= m <= 100), k (1 <= k <= 100).
```

Input file will be terminated by `0 0 0`.

### Output:

For each case output the number of ways that all chocolates could be distributed on a single line.

Sample Input:

```
1 1 1
4 2 2
5 3 2
0 0 0
```

Output:

```
1 
2
3
```

Original page: http://acm.whu.edu.cn/learn/problem/detail?problem_id=1031

I have tried recursive method but exceeded time limit. Then I tried to substitute recursion with a queue but exceeded memory limit. Is this problem about dynamic programming? Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have u tried to add some pruning in your resursive method? ie. if the remaining candies cannot be distributed to the rest of friends due to the limitation, u can just stop that.

also u can use DP method. let f[i][j][k] means the number of possible ways that having distributed for the first i friends, the ith friend having j candies, and there are k remaining candies.

```
boundary: f[0][0][n]=1;
u can use forward recurrence:
f[i+1][j+l][k-(j+l)]+=f[i][j][k]; 0<=l<=K (K here is what in your input)
the final answer is sum(0<=i<=n)(f[m][i][0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the DP method !